# How to recover dropped table structure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I accidentally dropped a table which did not have any data but its a big table. Can i get the structure of the table somehow?
i tried

```
SELECT TOP 5000 * 
FROM  (SELECT COALESCE(Object_name(s2.objectid), 'Ad-Hoc')       AS ProcName, 
              execution_count, 
              s2.objectid, 
              (SELECT TOP 1 Substring(s2.text, statement_start_offset / 2 + 1, ( 
                            ( 
                            CASE 
                              WHEN 
                            statement_end_offset = -1 THEN 
                              ( 
                                                        Len( 
                              CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max), s2.text)) * 
                                                        2 
                              ) 
                                                        ELSE 
                            statement_end_offset 
                            END 
                            ) 
                            - statement_start_offset ) / 2 + 1)) AS 
              sql_statement, 
              last_execution_time 
       FROM   sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS s1 
              CROSS apply sys.Dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS s2) x 
WHERE  sql_statement NOT LIKE 'SELECT TOP 50 * FROM(SELECT %' 
--and OBJECTPROPERTYEX(x.objectid,'IsProcedure') = 1 
ORDER  BY last_execution_time DESC
```

But i could not get create table query. Help!

Comment: That's what SQL backups are for. You are backing up your DB, right?

Comment: No. :( ... 
I do not care about the data but i need the structure.

Comment: Any insert stored procedure that may have info about your table? any insert script in your app?

Comment: In principle it would be possible to use `sys.fn_dblog` to look at the transaction log. Identify the offending transaction and look at the logged delete statements for `sys.syscolpars` particularly but also `sys.sysschobjs`, `sys.sysrscols`, `sys.sysrowsets`,`sys.sysidxstats`, `sys.sysallocunits` and maybe other system objects depending on the definition of the table. Then use an approach like [How to recover deleted data from SQL Server](http://raresql.com/2011/10/22/how-to-recover-deleted-data-from-sql-sever/) to reverse engineer the log records. Quite a lot of work though.

Comment: And there is no guarantee that the necessary records are even still in the log.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ApexSQL Log tool for that:
http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/4-techniques-for-recovering-lost-tables-due-to-drop-table-operation/